# How do I pass correct Url.Action to a JQuery method without extra ampersand trouble?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to make an ajax call like so:

```
$('#Grid').load('@Url.Action("_AgentStatesGrid", "AgentStates", new { projectId = Model.SelectedProject, siteId = Model.SelectedSite })', null, refreshComplete);
```

Unfortunately, it gets interpreted as this:

```
$('#Grid').load('/AgentStates/_AgentStatesGrid?projectId=179&amp;siteId=0', null, refreshComplete);
```

As you can see, the &.a.m.p.; is there instead of the ampersand for the querystring (I put dots in because, duh, the web interprets it as an ampersand.., you get the idea)

I tried Url.Decode and that did nothing. I'm not sure I understand the problem so I have no clue how to fix it.

Comment: Try @Html.Raw(Url.Action("_AgentStatesGrid", "AgentStates", new { projectId = Model.SelectedProject, siteId = Model.SelectedSite }))

Comment: That did it Steve! Make it an answer so I can checkmark it please :-)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Try

```
 @Html.Raw(Url.Action("_AgentStatesGrid", "AgentStates", new { projectId = Model.SelectedProject, siteId = Model.SelectedSite }))
```

Thanks

Comment: I'm somewhat disappointed that this is required.  I can't help but think that the usual use-case for Url.Action is as a link, thereby (technically) requiring Html.Raw in almost all cases (the case of a single parameter working correctly is more by accident than design).  But I guess people have been struggling with this since 2011, so nuthin's gunna' change now...

Comment: Couldn't agree more.  Should encode each parameter, not the resulting url.

Comment: I just "lost" some precious life time debugging this miserable bug. ;)

Comment: Saved my bacon, seriously who encodes the whole damn thing not just the params.

Comment: bug, seriously? What about this usage where it does the job correct. 

onclick="location.href = '@Url.Action("UserClone", "Preview", new { sourceId = 1, targetId = 2 })';"