# Parameters not being properly passed to controller action from view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, parameters, null

For an app I am working on, I've got the following Razor code for a View I am working on:

```
@Html.InputFor(m => m.Property1);   // A date
@Html.InputFor(m => m.Property2);   // Some other date
@Html.InputFor(m => m.SomeOtherProperty);  // Something else.
<a href='#' id='some-button'>Button Text Here</a>

<!-- SNIP: Extra code that dosen't matter -->

<script>
  var $someButton = $('#some-button');

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $someButton.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.open('@Url.Action("Foo", "Home", new {p1 = Model.Property1, p2 = Model.Property2, pX = Model.SomeOtherProperty})', '_blank');
    });
  });
</script>
```

...upon a comment, I checked the rendered HTML.  The values come with values, as expected...

```
<input name="Property1" data-val="true" data-val-required="(Required)" type="text" value="1/1/2013">
<input name="Property2" data-val="true" data-val-required="(Required)" type="text" value="4/11/2013">
<input name="SomeOtherProperty" data-val="true" data-val-required="(Required)" type="text" value="42">
<a href='#' id='some-button'>Button Text Here</a>

<script>
  var $someButton = $('#some-button');

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $someButton.click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      window.open('http://localhost:xxxx/Home/Foo?p1=1%2F1%2F2013&amp;p2=4%2F11%2F2013&amp;pX=42', '_blank');
    });
  });
</script>
```

...and on the server side...

```
public ActionResult Foo(string p1, string p2, string pX)
{
  var workModel = new FooWorkModel
  {
    Property1 = p1,
    Property2 = p2,
    SomeOtherProperty = pX
  };

  // Do something with this model, dosen't really matter from here, though.
  return new FileContentResult(results, "application/some-mime-type");
}
```

I've noticed that only the first parameter (`p1`) is getting a value from the front end; all my other parameters are being passed null values!

**Question**: Why is the ActionResult being passed null values, when some value is assigned for these other fields?  Or, a complimentary question: why would only the first parameter be successfully passing its value, while everything else is failing?

Comment: What does your rendered HTML look like?  Are Property2 and SomeOtherProperty set to blank values when the page loads?

Comment: Property 1, 2, and SomeOtherProperty are all populated.  It's worth noting, that the process I'm working with requires that information is entered, and a Search link clicked.  This submits a copy of the model (with the filled in information), which acts as the criteria for a search.  This information is populated into a List of submodels, and that List having a count of > 0 allows the links I am coding to even be presented.

Comment: Andrew, window.open('@Url.Action("Foo", "Home", new {p1 = Model.Property1, p2 = Model.Property2, pX = Model.SomeOtherProperty})', '_blank'); what this line generates in HTML? The values from inputs that you pasted won't be used when that js runs.

Comment: Posted generated URL.  I notice the `&amp;` as well as various escaped characters.

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336532/how-do-i-pass-correct-url-action-to-a-jquery-method-without-extra-ampersand-trou

Comment: @vladimir77 - Make an answer based around that, and I'll accept, that solved my problem.

Comment: @Andrew thanks :) but i didn't resolve it yourself and only found the prepared response. To tell the truth i dont understand why MVC has that behaviour, i always use parametrized url.action directly without 'raw'. Good luck :) PS You could add answer to your question.

Comment: @vladimir77: I'll go ahead and do that.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is being caused by the escaped URL being generated by `Url.Action()`.  (Source: [How do I pass correct Url.Action to a JQuery method without extra ampersand trouble?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7336532/how-do-i-pass-correct-url-action-to-a-jquery-method-without-extra-ampersand-trou))

Simply add a `@Html.Raw()` call around the `Url.Action()`, and data will flow as intended.

```
 window.open('@Html.Raw(Url.Action("Foo", "Home", new {p1 = Model.Property1, p2 = Model.Property2, pX = Model.SomeOtherProperty}))', '_blank');
```